# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable map(), list() , set() do not solve my problem

Tags: python

I'm writing a program to efficiantly divide by three, but I can extract the individual numbers from the int.

I have already tried map() and list() and set() and they have not worked

```
num = 1
while True:
    num = num + 1
    threetest = 0
    digits = list(num)                 #(This is line 17)
    for a in range ( 0, len(str(num))):
        threetest = threetest + digits[a]
    if (treetest % 3) != 0:
        ...
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 17, in 
    digits = list(num)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

I would expect to be able to add up the induvidual digits of a number like 936 and then divide the sum by 3 to efficiantly find if it is a multipule of 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a `list` of the digits of type `int`, try

`digits = list(map(int, str(num)))`

`num` is an `int`, which isn't an iterable. First get a `str` of `num`, then iterate over it and make each digit an `int`, and pack it all in a `list`.

Also, the code below is more pythonic:

```
num = 1
while True:
    num += 1
    three_test = 0
    digits = list(map(int, str(num)))
    for digit in range(digits):
        three_test += digit
    if (tree_test % 3) != 0:
```

Comment: Notice that this is _not_ how you'd normally solve this problem in Python, the idiomatic way would be: `threetest = sum(int(digit) for digit in str(num))` (see my answer.)

Comment: I was being myopic. You're absolutely right. I have up voted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired effect by replacing this:

```
threetest = 0
digits = list(num)
for a in range (0, len(str(num))):
    threetest = threetest + digits[a]
```

With this:

```
threetest = 0
for digit in str(num):
    threetest += int(digit)
```

Or even simpler (and way more idiomatic):

```
threetest = sum(int(digit) for digit in str(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```
>>> digits = [ast.literal_eval(i) for i in str(a)]
>>> digits
[3, 4, 6]
```

You can replace,

```
digits = list(num)
```

with,

```
digits = [int(i) for i in str(a)]
```

Comment: Talk about overkill :( why would anybody use `ast.literal_eval()` for parsing an `int`, when we have `int()`?